# ASP.NET MVC 5, how to enable validation annotation on viewmodel that composes other view models?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

Well I have a very complex User Profile system in a social network application I am building. The profile page has tabs that distinguishes each category of user profile information: Basic, Education, Job. There is a UserProfileViewModel sitting on top of everything, which composes of inner view models such as BasicViewModel, EducationViewModel and JobViewModel. Consider the structure as below:

```
    public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public BasicViewModel basic { get; set; }
    public EducationViewModel education { get; set; }
    public JobViewModel job { get; set; }
}

public class BasicViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfRegistration { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Biography")]
    public string Biography { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteQuotes { get; set; }
}

public class EducationViewModel{
    public string EducationStatus { get; set; }
    public List<University> Universities { get; set; }
    public string CourseStatus { get; set; }
    public string CourseSpecialization { get; set; }
    public List<string> EducationEvents { get; set; }
}

public class JobViewModel
{
    public string WorkStatus { get; set; }
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Organization
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Year { get; set; }
    public int TimePeiod { get; set; }
}

public class University: Organization
{
    public string Degree { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
}

public class Company: Organization
{
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

So the question is, does data annotation for model validation(both server and client side) work for a model that has composite structure like this? If so, do I just place annotation like I usually do with simple view models? If not, how can I achieve this in alternative ways? Please help.

Comment: Yes it does, the fact that  each ViewModel contains others has no effect on validation.  Any valdiation attributes found will be honored per your needs with Data annotation.  NOTE: there is also server side Validation that can be done as well.  It is called just prior to the actionmethod being "entered" by the post or get.  You merely need to add the interface to the viewmodels where you want server side validation.... this is how ModelState gets set to valid on server side.  The client side validation doesn't allow postback if invalid.

Comment: If the properties in your `BasicViewModel` (and other 'sub' models) are decorated with validation attributes, they will be respected if you render a view using `ProfileViewModel`

Comment: I see, thats excellent. Thank you. Now I have another question about data binding. I will explain in a post, thanks again.

Comment: As has been said, Yes... it does work, however there are some gotchas.  For instance, Attributes will only be validated for contained view models that are instantiated.  This means that in some cases you can get no validation because no instantiated model exists on the server (this is particularly the case when you have Required attributes for sub-models).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any single view model may contain other viewmodels like this:

This model is server side:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyBigViewModel : IValidatableObject 
    {
       public MyBigViewModel(){
          MyOtherViewModel = new MyOtherViewModel();
          MyThirdViewModel = new MyThirdViewModel();
      }
      public MyOtherViewModel {get;set;}
      public MyThiddViewModel {get;set;} 

    public void Post(){
           //you can do something here based on post back 
           //like maybe this where the post method here processes new data
           MyOtherViewModel.Post();

    }

}
```

The controller could look like this:

```
  public ActionResult UserList (MyBigViewModel uvm){
      if(ModelState.IsValid){
         uvm.Post();
         return View(uvm);

      }
    return View(uvm);
  }
```

You can implement the IValidateableObject to do "server side" validation.  In the example above however, we want each viewmodel to "contain" it's own model for validation.

Each viewmodel property can use data annotations "contained" in only that viewmodel.  It's a very nice way to "Contain" what you want where you want.

I very often use multiple Viewmodels in main VM and pass them in with partial views as needed.

Comment: I think you dont understand what I mean by this question. In your case the model only contains simple primitive data. But if my view model contains complex structures like an inner view model, can I make data annotation validation too?

Comment: I didn't see any annotations in your viewmodels, therefore I felt you were not familiar with them that's why I showed the simple example.  But as I said in first comment you should not have any issues just because you have viewmodels of viewmodels.  It doesn't matter to the client side because the content is either there or it isn't.  The client side doesn't have  cognizance of how the data is ordered or contained.  As long as the view has address-ablity that is all that matters.

Comment: I see. Well I do understand how data annotation works, at least in a simple model consisting of only primitive data. I deliberately removed the data annotation so that my code will look shorter and easier to read. If you look at the code, I did forget to remove annotation for the biography data field in basicviewmodel. This should tell enough that I do know something about it.

Comment: Very good, looks like you are on your way, with each Viewmodel implementing data annotations and each being contained by the masterviewmodel everything should work as you've intended!