# How to define a property with validation attributes once, then use property in multiple view models?

Tags: asp.net, interface, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I have a number of user account controllers and view models implemented for the purposes of administering user accounts.  Many of these view models contain the same properties (e.g. Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, Password) with the same data validation annotations.  I'm trying to figure how to (or if its even possible to) split out my validation annotations in to a separate interface/class so that I only have to define those annotations once.  The ultimate goal is being that I don't have to repeat the validation annotations (keep it DRY), and server side and client side validation will work.

I got real close, but couldn't cross the finish line.  Consider these two view models:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IRegisterViewModel))]
public class RegisterViewModel : IRegisterViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(IAccountPassword))]
public class ChangePasswordViewModel : IAccountPassword
{
    // this version is for already authenticated users that want to change their password
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

With these annotation interfaces:

```
public interface IRegisterViewModel : IAccountName, IAccountEmail, IAccountUserName, IAccountPassword { }

public interface IAccountEmail
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email address")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    string Email { get; set; }
}

public interface IAccountName
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "First Name must be at least 2 letters")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First Name is too long")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Last Name must be at least 2 letters")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last Name is too long")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

public interface IAccountPassword
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Data validation does not work (doesn't appear that it even gets wired up) when I use an interface composed of multiple interfaces, as in the case of `IRegisterViewModel`.  However, data validation DOES work in the case when I use `IAccountPassword` (when implementing only one interface).

These are just two examples...  I have many more account controllers/models/views that are used to admin a user account, and many of them use some combination of common properties.  It seems like it would be a common desire to define these once, rather than repeat yourself by defining them on multiple view models (and have to maintain updates to those definitions across view models).

I've seen several other posts on SO with folks trying to do basically the same.  Generally the question/answer only deals with a single inheritance, not multiple like I'm trying to do.  Others are many years old and/or are tagged with older versions of MVC (so I don't know if they are valid anymore or not).  Regardless, I haven't found anything that works.

[This was an interesting question/answer approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109364/asp-net-mvc-5-how-to-enable-validation-annotation-on-viewmodel-that-composes-ot) that composed the required view model from one or more "sub" view models.  I suppose I could try this approach if nothing else comes about, but it seems clunky and error prone to create a view model with a single property, then have to refer to an Email address from my parent view model using `Model.Email.Email`.

Surely this is a common issue that I don't know how to search for the correct answer or I'm just not connecting all the dots.